# MySQL query not pulling up records for next year

Tags: mysql, sql, select, date-format

I have a basic query that will pull records from two tables, and the criteria is that the date is equal to, or greater than today. It will fetch everything for this year only. It looks like this:

```
ds_postmeta.meta_value >=Date_Format(CURDATE(), ('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Any ideas? I have never seen this before

Comment: If at all possible, store dates using one of the date datatypes - even when using an EAV model. If you really can't, then at least store them in the yyyy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date_format` takes a date and converts it to a string, which means you are comparing two strings, forcing lexicographical comparison instead of comparing real dates. Instead, you should user [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert `meta_value` to a date before you compare it to the current date:

```
STR_TO_DATE(ds_postmeta.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y') >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for pointing me in the right direction. Since this is a WP site, and custom fields are automatically strings, all I had to do was change the date format in the table to yyyy-mm-dd and convert it to a date, then order by the date field. It works fine. And I am not worried about the date formatting in the db since I can convert it to mm dd, yyyy with PHP for my widget.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what's stored in `meta_value`.

If what's in there is a string representation of a date value in `'mm/dd/yyyy'` format, there's a problem with the comparison, because that's going to be a character by character comparison. And if the "month" isn't equal, the comparison will end with a result *before* it checks the year. The comparison, as it's written, is going to say that December two years ago is *after* today (e.g. May 2015).

To compare that as an actual "date" value, you'd really need to convert that string into an actual `DATE`, and then do the comparison to another `DATE`, something like this:

```
STR_TO_DATE(ds_postmeta.meta_value,'%m/%d/%Y') > CURDATE()
```